# SQL Server 2005 : using OR operator with LIKE operator

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can I use `LIKE` operator with the `OR` operator in SQL Server 2005? For example:

```
SELECT * 
  FROM table 
 WHERE column_name LIKE '%boo%' OR '%bar%'
```

This does not seems to work !

**EDIT 1** : RESPONSE TO FIRST ANSWER POSTED:

Cool, that works ! but I just found for the first time that your order conditions do not work with like ... I want to ask is this normal or am I making a mistake? please see below to see what I mean

```
select * 
from <table> 
where col_name = 'VAL-QWE' 
      AND scenario like '%xxx%'
      OR scenario like '%yyy%'
```

if you execute this query, sql server does not cares for `col_name = 'VAL-QWE'`  condition at all, it just looks at the like condition ?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
select * 
from table where 
column_name like '%boo%' 
or column_name like '%bar%'
```

You need to repeat what the condition is being tested on.  In this case, you need to repeat `column_name` in your second conditional `like` clause.

The `like` or any conditional test does not persist from the previous statement/test.

Comment: +1: leveraging [Full Text Search](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms142571.aspx) would perform better though.

Comment: @OMGPonies absolutely, I couldn't agree more.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but please consider re-reading my question I have updated it. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You have totally changed the meaning of your question by your editing, not a good thing to do!

In your modified example, the 'AND' is evaluated before the 'OR' , so your sql is doing the following:

```
select * from <table> where (col_name = 'VAL-QWE' AND scenario like '%xxx%') or scenario like '%yyy%'
```

but what I think you want is

```
select * from <table> where col_name = 'VAL-QWE' AND (scenario like '%xxx%' or scenario like '%yyy%')
```

Answer (score -1):

Plain and simple use sql regexp:

```
select * from <table> where col_name = 'VAL-QWE' AND scenario REGEXP 'xxx|yyy';
```

Comment: REGEXP is not a feature of SQL Server at this time.